# Отображение Navigation Drawer во всех активностях или фрагментах

Tags: android-fragment, activity, kotlin, android-navigation-drawer

Сразу прошу не забрасывать камнями, так как совершенно не умею программировать. Нигде не учился, никто не учит. Гуглю сам. При этом сделал уже 4 приложения методом тыка)

Итак вопрос: Создаём Navigation Drawer из Андроид студии. 
Выводим свои пункты меню в strings ибо андроид студия почему то этого не делает.

Дальше хотелось бы, чтобы при клике на пункты меню менялся текст на экране. Вызвать новую активность вроде получается, но открывается пустая активность. Без Navigation Drawer. Всё, что гуглится по этому поводу имеет совершенно другую структуру кода, и непонятно, что куда копировать-вставить, чтобы заработало.  Многие советуют использовать фрагменты, но опять таки, все образцы кода найденные в интернете непохожи на мои и непонятно что куда писать.

Вот мой код:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> return true
            else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_main_page -> {
                // Handle the camera action
            }
            R.id.nav_poisk -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_history ->  {

            }
            R.id.nav_ischu_zhilyo -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_dobavit_predlo -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_help-> {

            }
        }

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

Единственное, что пока получилось, это заставить один из пунктов меню открывать новую активность. К этому я тоже пришел методом тыка вставив строку  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_poisk);` в этот кусок кода:

```
  R.id.nav_poisk -> {


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_poisk);
```

По логике вещей, точно также можно в другие пункты меню вставить другие активности, и они будут открываться при клике на пункты меню? Но есть проблема! Активность PoiskActivity открывается без Navigation Drawer (Без боковой панели).

**Как сделать, чтобы боковая панель открывалась на всех активностях, или фрагментах? Я уже столько всего прочитал, что запутался окончательно. Мне бы просто строку кода и место, куда её вставить. Был бы очень благодарен)**

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не поняли суть паттерна Navigation Drawer. Их не должно быть несколько, как правило. При клике на пункты в меню либо меняется контент(фрагмент) на экране в той же активити, либо стартует новая поверх. Кратко так.

Comment: Это я понял. Я просто не знаю, что и куда написать в коде, чтобы менялся этот контент(фрагмент) на экране в этой активити.

Comment: В `onNavigationItemSelected` все происходит, самая обычная работа с фрагментами через транзакции. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions

Answer (score 0):

Евгений дело говорит (парень, что прокомментировал вопрос). Прокинуть какую-то сущность насквозь, через все **activity** и **фрагменты** - нельзя. Можно создать **activity**, в котором инициализировать **Navigation Drawer** и переключать текущий фрагмент по клику в меню. При этом, вы всегда должны находиться в одном **activity**.  Делать все приложение в одном "окне" не рекомендуется, если приложение "большое", можно усложнить себе жизнь как следует. Как вариант, вы можете посмотреть другие меню в https://android-arsenal.com/tag/138?sort=created

Comment: С чего вы решили, что делать все приложение в одном "окне" не рекомендуется. На чем ваше мнение основано? А как же антипаттерн Single - Activity? Также я с вами не согласен с высказыванием: При этом, вы всегда должны находиться в одном activity. Текущий шаблон Navigation Drawer построен на библиотеке Navigation Library, а там уже не обязательно находится в одной активити, можно переключаться свободно между группами активити и фрагментами